# Flattening multiple nested list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Supposing I have a multiple nested list of following structure:

```
['p', [['p', 'q'], [['~p', '~r'], [['r', '~s'], ['s', '~q']]]]]
```

where every second element of nested list is another nested list (except for innermost list), I want to output to extract all list with the strings such that my output appears as follows:

```
['p', ['p', 'q'], ['~p', '~r'], ['r', '~s'], ['s', '~q']]
```

I have implemented the following code:

```
def flatten_nested_list(nested_list):
    flat_list = []
    for item in nested_list:
        if isinstance(item, list) and isinstance(item[1], list):
            flat_list.append(item[0])
            flat_list.extend(flatten_nested_list(item[1]))
        else:
            flat_list.append(item)
    return flat_list

nested_list = ['p', [['~p', 'q'], [['~p', '~r'], [['r', '~s'], ['s', '~q']]]]]
flat_result = flatten_nested_list(nested_list)
print(flat_result)
```

However my function does not handle the innermost list properly and my output is as follows:

```
['p', ['~p', 'q'], ['~p', '~r'], ['r', '~s'], 's', '~q']
```

Can any change be suggested so that the innermost list be handled properly ?

Comment: could you an inner list like `[['r', '~s'], `p`, ['s', '~q']]` ?

Comment: That seems ambiguous to me. Unless you have a rule that says what the inner-most list looks like. I mean, it looks like a scheme list where each pair is replaced by a size-2 python list. Except for that ending rule (in scheme the last list is null, not the last element). How to you know if `[a, [b, [c, d]]]` means that there is only one element `[a,[b,[c,d]]]`, or if there are 2 elements `a` and `[b,[c,d]]`, or 3 elements `a`, `b` and `[c,d]` or 4 elements `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`. Your code choose the last (and only approximately objective) option. But you say the 3rd should be chosen. Why?(...)

Comment: (...) Do you know for sure that the last element has to be a list of non-list? So `[c,d]`-like. If you have more information, please share them. As shown, I would say that this is unsolvable (not from a coding perspective. But from a decision perspective: there is no way to decide that what you got is wrong and what you want is correct. At least no way that you've shared)

Comment: My goal is to parse 2CNF through ply lex and yacc and obtain the clauses as list of lists. The characters within the list are actually disjunctions so something like (r \/ ~s) /\ p /\ (s \/ ~q) (/\ is conjunction, \/ is disjunction) would parse through as [['r', '~s'], ['p', ['s', '~q']]] according to my grammar rules, which is why I want to flatten them to work with clauses

Comment: Then comes the other question: how to you know which are conjunction which are disjunction? I get why you *want* to do this. But I still don't get why you *could* do this. This seems ambiguous. `(r /\ ~s) \/ p /\ (s \/ ~q)` would have which representation? Or (r \/ ~s) /\ p /\ s /\ ~q ?

Comment: Again, may be with extra rules, that is feasible. Such as "I know for sure that this is a conjunction of multiple terms, some being terminals such as `p`, some other begin disjunction of two terminals, and the last one is a disjunction".  But you need to state those rules. From what you said, there is no way to know how those are nested.

Comment: You're right my grammar rules in fact are a bit inconsistent, I'll have to fix them up a bit first thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can use recursion:

```py
lst = ["p", [["p", "q"], [["~p", "~r"], [["r", "~s"], ["s", "~q"]]]]]


def flatten(lst):
    if isinstance(lst[-1], list):
        yield lst[0]
        yield from flatten(lst[-1])
    else:
        yield lst


print(list(flatten(lst)))
```

Prints:

```
['p', ['p', 'q'], ['~p', '~r'], ['r', '~s'], ['s', '~q']]
```

---

EDIT:

```py
lst = ["p", [["~p", "q"], [["~q", "r"], "~r"]]]


def flatten(lst):
    match [lst[0], lst[1]]:
        case str(), list():
            yield lst[0]
            yield from flatten(lst[1])
        case list(), list():
            yield from flatten(lst[0])
            yield from flatten(lst[1])
        case list(), str():
            yield from flatten(lst[0])
            yield lst[1]
        case _:
            yield lst


print(list(flatten(lst)))
```

Prints:

```
['p', ['~p', 'q'], ['~q', 'r'], '~r']
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, but if I try a case such as `['p', [['~p', 'q'], [['~q', 'r'], '~r']]]` it won't work right ?

Comment: @Jimmeh Because the last element has first element list and second element non-list, which is different than the rest.

Comment: @Jimmeh I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the list format is consistent to what you describe above, I think you can keep track of a boolean variable (`hasList` in below code) to keep track if the second element in the list is a nested list. If not, you can enclose the returned list in another list to avoid the flatten issue above

```
def flatten_nested_list(nested_list):
    flat_list = []
    hasList = False
    for item in nested_list:
        if isinstance(item, list) and isinstance(item[1], list):
            flat_list.append(item[0])
            flat_list.extend(flatten_nested_list(item[1]))
            hasList = True
        else:
            flat_list.append(item)
    
    if hasList:
        return flat_list
    else:
        return [flat_list]

nested_list = ['p', [['~p', 'q'], [['~p', '~r'], [['r', '~s'], ['s', '~q']]]]]
flat_result = flatten_nested_list(nested_list)
print(flat_result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Linear time solution (the other answers take quadratic time):

```
def flatten_nested_list(nested_list):
    flat_list = []
    while isinstance(nested_list[1], list):
        item, nested_list = nested_list
        flat_list.append(item)
    flat_list.append(nested_list)
    return flat_list
```